# How to print procedure cursor which has output paramater on Datagrip without paramaters pop-up

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, datagrip

I'm trying to execute oracle sql+plus statements.

The statement works on Oracle SQL Developer.

```
var RC refcursor;
exec tplco.PKG_SOMETIHNG.MY_PROCEDURE('1', null, :RC);
print RC;
```

There are 3 parameters.
First and second is input parameter and last one is output parameter.
I thgought that procedure bind cursor in 3rd parmater(rc; REFCURSOR).

I tried to execute that statements on Datagrip.
[datagrip parameter binding window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd9Wj.png)

I aleady declared that value(rc; REFCURSOR) but,
When I execute this query, then that pop-up appears every time.

How can I get the result of cursor result ?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on Oracle data source in *Database Explorer*, click on the driver name (right to connection type), select *Go to driver*, click on *Options* tab and select *Generic SQL* in *Other | Dialect*.